# SciKits.umfpack installation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, python-2.x, suitesparse, umfpack

I am trying to install on UBuntu 20.4 the scikits.umfpack python package because it is needed as a dependency for this [python packages](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/CBBresearch/Yu/mn/itm_probe/doc/qmbpmn-tools.html) for network analysis on my dissertation.

I am also using python 2.7.18, because the tool I want to use ONLY runs with python 2.7. I have installed numpy, scipy, pyparsing and graphviz from the other dependencies and installed the tool using the information [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/CBBresearch/Yu/mn/itm_probe/doc/qmbpmn-tools.html) successfully.

When I try to install the umfpack package using the pip command  pip install scikit-umfpack, I get the following errors:

```
> DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality. Collecting scikit-umfpack   Using cached scikit-umfpack-0.3.3.tar.gz (26 kB) Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy>=1.16.6 in /home/mema/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from scikit-umfpack) (1.16.6) Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: scipy>=1.0.0rc1 in /home/mema/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from scikit-umfpack) (1.2.3) Building wheels for collected packages: scikit-umfpack   Building wheel for scikit-umfpack (setup.py) ... error   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:    command: /usr/bin/python2.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-EAQsAc/scikit-umfpack/setup.py'"'"';
__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-EAQsAc/scikit-umfpack/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-UlwZj1
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-EAQsAc/scikit-umfpack/   Complete output (30 lines):   umfpack_info:   customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries umfpack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib']   /home/mema/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:446: UserWarning:
      UMFPACK sparse solver (https://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/umfpack/)
      not found. Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [umfpack]) or by setting
      the UMFPACK environment variable.
    return cl().get_info(notfound_action)
    NOT AVAILABLE
     Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-install-EAQsAc/scikit-umfpack/setup.py", line 250, in <module>
      setup_package()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-EAQsAc/scikit-umfpack/setup.py", line 247, in setup_package
      setup(**metadata)
    File "/home/mema/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 137, in setup
      config = configuration()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-EAQsAc/scikit-umfpack/setup.py", line 143, in configuration
      config.add_subpackage('scikits.umfpack')
    File "/home/mema/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1036, in add_subpackage
      caller_level = 2)
    File "/home/mema/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1005, in get_subpackage
      caller_level = caller_level + 1)
    File "/home/mema/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 942, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
      config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
    File "scikits/umfpack/setup.py", line 19, in configuration
      umf_info['libraries'].insert(0, 'rt')   KeyError: 'libraries'   ----------------------------------------   ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikit-umfpack   Running setup.py clean for scikit-umfpack Failed to build scikit-umfpack Installing collected packages: scikit-umfpack
    Running setup.py install for scikit-umfpack ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python2.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-EAQsAc/scikit-umfpack/setup.py'"'"';
__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-EAQsAc/scikit-umfpack/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-T0Fq3b/install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/mema/.local/include/python2.7/scikit-umfpack
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-EAQsAc/scikit-umfpack/
    Complete output (30 lines):
    umfpack_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries umfpack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib']
    /home/mema/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:446: UserWarning:
        UMFPACK sparse solver (https://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/umfpack/)
        not found. Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [umfpack]) or by setting
        the UMFPACK environment variable.
      return cl().get_info(notfound_action)
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-EAQsAc/scikit-umfpack/setup.py", line 250, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-EAQsAc/scikit-umfpack/setup.py", line 247, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "/home/mema/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 137, in setup
        config = configuration()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-EAQsAc/scikit-umfpack/setup.py", line 143, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('scikits.umfpack')
      File "/home/mema/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1036, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "/home/mema/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1005, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "/home/mema/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 942, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scikits/umfpack/setup.py", line 19, in configuration
        umf_info['libraries'].insert(0, 'rt')
    KeyError: 'libraries'
    ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python2.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-EAQsAc/scikit-umfpack/setup.py'"'"';
__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-EAQsAc/scikit-umfpack/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-T0Fq3b/install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/mema/.local/include/python2.7/scikit-umfpack Check the logs for full command output.
```

NOTE: I have tried it on windows, i get errors there as well.
Also, I have tried to git clone the repo, tried PYcharm, ANaconda, suitespasre and C dev tools, nothing worked for me. Obviously I do something wrong!

Please help me I'm stuck for months...

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea why. But i had a similar problem and the only solution was to install it first in visual studio 2022: first i installed wheel and then scikit-umfpack.

Then i returned to visual studio code and i could install it correctly.